# How to scroll a html page with a hand tool?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to scroll on a html page by clicking on the content as normally does a pdf viewer,
I already tried this plugin ["Jquery Content Drag Scroller"](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Jquery-Content-Drag-Scroller/) but it seems only scrolling vertically, do you have any other idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/touchScroller.html

Is that you want to make?

Comment: nothing behind the link

Comment: link is broken.